# Not getting actual minutes in SQL DateDiff

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I searched in different places and found below queries. I am using the following queries to get the actual minutes difference in `SQL`. The dates I provide are the same day. I need difference in minutes only but `SQL` is returning 35 instead of 5 minutes in the first query. And the second query return milliseconds.

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,GETDATE(), CONVERT(datetime,'2016-08-11 16:04:24'))%3600/60 AS MinuteDiff 

 SELECT datediff(minute,GETDATE(), CONVERT(datetime,'2016-08-11 16:04:24')) as MinutesDiff
```

What is missing. Please help.

I need to put a condition that if time is less than 20 minutes then

do this

else

do this

**Updated:**

The issue occurs when i use GetDate(). When I use a fix date it works fine

Comment: The second one works for me, although I changed the time to 7:25 as I am on eastern time.  Since it is now 7:30 it returns -5, if I switch the parameters to datediff it is 5.  Also there is no need for an explicit convert.   SELECT datediff(minute, '2016-08-11 7:25:24',GETDATE()) as MinutesDiff

Comment: it is returning -128160.    SELECT datediff(minute,'2016-08-11 16:35:35.983',GETDATE()) as MinutesDiff. It should return 1 minute only

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean when you say the second query returns milliseconds. Also, when you say "less than 20 minutes" how precise do you need to be?

Comment: Not sure what time zone you or the server is in, what is returned by select getdate() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the `GETDATE()` after your datetime value, other wise in your case you will get the minutes in negative value.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(datetime,'2016-08-11 16:04:24'), GETDATE()) AS MinuteDiff
```

The current `GETDATE()` is `2016-08-11 17:05:39.053`, so it returns `61`.

Then based on the value, using `IF ... ELSE ...` you can do your expected operation:

```
IF DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(datetime,'2016-08-11 16:04:24'), GETDATE()) < 20
    PRINT 'With in 20 mins'
ELSE
    PRINT 'More than 20 mins'
```

Comment: Not getting that. I am using SQL Server 2008. Is this matter ?

Comment: Can you execute the `IF .. ELSE ...` block, which I added in the answer.

Comment: Yes, i execute it. For fix date it is working fine. But when i provide GetDate() its result is wrong.

Comment: @Abdul: May be your server having wrong datetime. What it returns if you execute `SELECT GATEDATE()` ?

Comment: System date is ok. When i provide date taken from get date() as fix , it works. But when i directly use GetDate() function , it shows opposite.

Comment: @Abdul: Opposite means, it returns in negative value?

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry for the initial poor explanation.

I use something like the following frequently this will return a INT and decide if it's then you can do the logic on it, equal to,  not equal less than greater than etc.

If it is true it will return a 1 or it is false a 0. You can get it to return columns or set it to a string.

Hope it helps

```
select
   Case
   When DateDiff(minute,[column],Getdate()) > 20 then 1 else 0 
end as [alias]
```

Comment: I'm now on a train so going to flesh out

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what your after...although you probably need to switch out the date components as appropriate for your usage.

```
    select 
            case
            when 
            (SELECT datediff(minute,GETDATE(), CONVERT(datetime,'2016-08-11 06:00:00'))) < 20 then
              (select 'do this') 
           else
              (select 'do something else')
           end as answer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want minute span between two datetime, then your second one is enough.

`SELECT datediff(n, CONVERT(datetime,'2016-08-11 16:04:24'),GETDATE()) as MinutesDiff`

you can use [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for your further

```
select 
    case when 
           datediff(n, CONVERT(datetime,'2016-08-11 16:04:24'),GETDATE()) < 20 then
              `your code`
           else
              `your else code`
           end minte
```